# Autolayout - Position by Percentage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'd like to map dots along a line.

[image: line across screen]

The line length depends on device and orientation and is always stretched across the whole screen. Therfore it would make most sense to me to **position** the dots using a **relative percentage** value.

So far I only found constraints being defined in some sort of point value ([Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/constraintFundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH2-SW2))

Is it possible to use percentage values as constraints as well? Any ideas on how to position these dots in a scalable way ... or do I need do this conversion/positioning "manually"?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes, you can position the dot as a fraction of the view's width. The NSLayoutConstraint method, constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:, has that multiplier parameter that lets you use a fractional relationship between a superview and its subview. The superview's right edge will be the width of that view (the screen if its a full width view), so if you create a constraint like below, the dot will be positioned at a fractional distance along the line:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      [self.view removeConstraint:self.leftConDark];
      [self.view removeConstraint:self.leftConLight];
      NSLayoutConstraint *lcd = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.darkButton 
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                                toItem:self.view 
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight 
                                                            multiplier:.5 
                                                              constant:0];
      NSLayoutConstraint *lcl = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.lightButton 
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                                toItem:self.view 
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight 
                                                            multiplier:.9 
                                                              constant:0];
      [self.view addConstraints:@[lcd,lcl]];
}
```

In this example I'm positioning two UIButtons (info type dark and light). I added them in IB, and made IBOutlets to their constraints they have to the left side of the view (that's what the system gave me, it could have been to the right side -- it doesn't matter since you just delete them anyway. If you are making the dots in code, you wouldn't need to do this). In code I remove those constraints, then add new ones that will put the center of the buttons at 50% and 90% of the way across the screen.

Comment: +1 I agree regarding the use of `multiplier` and `NSLayoutAttributeRight` (though I might do `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` to `NSLayoutAttributeRight`, but Bernd undoubtedly gets the idea). Wonderful.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for the correction -- I sometimes forget what things get updated when as far as frames and bounds are concerned. I had thought that the view's NSLayoutAttributeRight wouldn't reflect the correct value upon rotation unless the code was in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: @Rob, thanks again -- no need for forgiveness, I'm still trying to wrap my head around layout constraints. I've updated the answer.

Comment: You do not need to remove constraints directly.  In IB, select the 'placeholder' constraints one at a time (click the cog-down-arrow and choose 'Select and edit...') then check the 'remove at build time' box.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for the great answer. Works like a charm. I was wondering if its possible to achieve the same from the IB alone instead of adding constraints programmatically?

Comment: @Isuru, yes, you can do this in IB now (I'm not sure it was possible at the time I wrote this answer). Make the constraint between the view's centerX and the superview's trailing. Edit the constraint, and give it a multiplier of whatever fraction of the way across the screen you want the view to be placed. Set the constant to 0.

Comment: @rdelmar Can you please elaborate on how to set the constraint between the views's centerX and the superview's trailing? I can't seem to find how to do it.

Comment: @Isuru, you do it similar to how Greg has in his answer. Make a normal trailing-trailing constraint, and then double click on the constraint in the size inspector to show the detail view that Greg shows in his point 4. You can then change the trailing to centerX for your view and modify the constant and multiplier how you want. You might want to switch which item is first -- if you're thinking of it a s a fraction of the way across the screen, then you want the first item to be your view, not the superview.

Answer (score 13):

I'm not an auto-layout expert (or even competent yet!) but as of XCode 6, you seem to be able to do this in IB.

1. Select the object.
2. Show the size inspector (click on ruler) [image: size inspector]
3. Double-click on the constraint rectangle (not obvious!  "Edit" takes you somewhere else)

[image: constraint rectangle]

4. Here you can set the multiplier just like in the answer above.

[image]