# How to setup constraints in storyboard with autolayout for dynamic position on different device sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, constraints

i have a question about how to setup constraints in a storyboard with autolayout if I want to guarantee multiscreen support so that all UI-controls are accessible and the UI is not messed up on smaller screen-size devices (IPhone 4s or IPhone SE) when I designing on a bigger screen-size device (IPhone 6). I have a design which is build up on a IPhone 6 (in a sketch-file) which I want to transfer to my storyboard. So in general I want to setup all the view stuff in a storyboard and not via code.

Here are my constraints. The button to the bottom has fixed height of 48 and a leadingMargin to the right and left and a vertical distance of 100 to the bottom. The top button has the equal height to the bottom button and a distance of 28 to the bottom button.

[image: Constraints]

Here is the designed View with the mentioned buttons on an IPhone 6. This is the default size where I want to setup the storyboard cause of the sketch file.

[image: Iphone 6]

Here is the View on an IPhone 4s

[image: Iphone 4s]

As you can see the buttons are to close to the middle cause of the fixed vertical distance and the fixed height. I mean this is obviously cause of the fixed values. So I made some research about percentage position like [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508491/autolayout-position-by-percentage) but is this the correct way? Also other ways looks so complicated to me. How can I prevent fixed values like the height and the vertical distance? Is there a way to set the fixed height of 48 for the IPhone 6 and then scale the button down (for IPhone SE) in regards to the screen size (the same for the bottom vertical distance and other fixed values)?

Can someone give me any advice how I can proceed here?

Comment: May be this link helps you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42085444/different-iphone-devices-with-single-storyboard-by-using-xcode-8

Comment: I am also looking for same thing...but did't find any success....

Comment: most of the times I used spacerviews .. means blank views with equal heights multiplier to manage space according to device resolution .. but you can also use `center Y` constraint(Not preferred) with some constants like [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/abz3kkyad2tp8tp/1.gif?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit complicated I try to explain it as much as I can.

> *Note: Auto-layout is just like constructing a building every thing step by step.*

Select **top button** and add these constraints **(Leading:8,Trailing:8, And select Aspect Ratio checkbox)** + And also add **"Horizontal center and Vertical center constraints"** select the **vertical center** constraint and change it's ***multiplier to 1.5 or increase or decrease it's value accordingly.***

> There should no error after this only warnings if any.

Select **second button** and add **Top constraint to 8.** Select both buttons and add constraints which are highlighted in screen short.[image]

Run and check on different screens. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

- bottomButton.bottom = superview.bottom * 0.9

OR

- Change the bottom constraint by code

  ```
      bottomConstraint.constant = xx
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
  ```